# Phonegap - Blank screen between native splash and index.html

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am making a phonegap app using `cordova CLI` (no `phonegap-build` or any other fancy stuff) for iOS and Android. I then compile the app using XCode/Eclipse.

I am using `jQuery Mobile` and some other javascript plugins for my project. So when my app loads, after the splash screen (native), the screen stays blank for about 2-5 seconds while all the javascript in my index page loads. I am trying to figure out a way to display a loading screen while all the `js` loads but haven't yet figured out how to do it.

So is there any method in the HTML, CSS or Javascript universe that can help me achieve this? I'm basically an iOS dev so this is new to me.

Here are my javascripts if you're curious. ;-)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flatUI/jquery.mobile.flatui.css" />
<script src="CSS.supports.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<link href='fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar.min.js'></script> 
<script src="swiper/jquery.slideme2.js"></script>
<link href="swiper/slideme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: I would say: Just debugging it a little bit should help. Deactivate the scripts step by step to figure out what script blocks your screen from showing up. Did you try to bind an onload to the body with a div which hovers the full screen and displays a loading image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set AutoHideSplashScreen to false in config.xml

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

So now u need to turn it off manually and u can do this by putting the next line on place where all your javascripts are loaded:

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

For example:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}
```

If u want to have another screen, u need to load it before loading javascripts. U can navigate to a static "welcome" page and load your scripts after.